# SAS - Convert/Format a datetime variable

Tags: datetime, formatting, timestamp, sas

I have a datetime variable that is formatted as follows:

```
 27AUG2014:08:56:26.959136
```

How can I reformat it so that it looks like this:

```
 2014-08-27:08:56:26.959136
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution:

```
data want;
set have;
  format newdt E8601DT26.6;
  newdt=currdt;
  put currdt= newdt=;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the closest I could get - technically they're not formats, they're changing the values to strings so this may not suit your requirements. It appears as though the picture format directives are lacking a directive for millisecond so using a custom format will only get you so far.

```
proc format;
  picture test low-high = '%Y-%0m-%0d:%0H:%0M:%0S' (datatype = datetime) ;
run ;


data x;
  * THIS GETS US EVERYTHING EXCEPT THE DECIMAL PLACE;
  x = datetime();  
  put x= 22.5;
  put x= datetime22.5;
  put x= test.;

  * TO GET THE DECIMAL THERES A BIT OF MUCKING AROUND;
  * SIMPLY CONCATENATE THE DECIMAL ONWARDS TO THE FORMATTED VALUE;
  length y decimal_as_string $30;
  decimal_as_string = cats(put(x,22.5));

  y = cats(  put(x,test.), 
             substr(decimal_as_string, index(decimal_as_string,'.'))
           );

  put y=;
run;
```

Here's a link to how the picture format works:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/026-2007.pdf

**EDIT:**

Actually, using @user2941280's format gets us closer, faster.  This will do it:

```
data _null;
  length my_date $30; 
  my_date = translate(put(datetime(),E8601DT26.6),':','T');
  put my_date=;
run;
```